# Javascript - Puppeteer - Text finding

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, webautomation

I am trying to figure out how to use Puppeteer to search an HTML page, for a product name.

For example the HTML is written out something like this:

```
<a class="example" href = "example_link">PRODUCT NAME</a>
```

What I am trying to get Puppeteer to do is find ***PRODUCT NAME*** through keywords, or the actual name of ***PRODUCT NAME***, and have it click on the text which would redirect the browser to the href link.

If you could help, that would be great!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you need to find a link by its text content to click on. If so, these are at least two ways:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, defaultViewport: null });
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    const textToFind = 'More information...';

    // Way 1.

    await page.goto('https://example.org/');

    const link1 = await page.evaluateHandle(
      text => [...document.querySelectorAll('a')].find(a => a.innerText === text),
      textToFind
    );
    await link1.click();
    await page.waitFor(3000);

    // Way 2.

    await page.goto('https://example.org/');

    const [link2] = await page.$x(`//a[text()="${textToFind}"]`);
    await link2.click();
    await page.waitFor(3000);

    await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

If you need to find a partial match, you can use `includes()` instead of `===` in the first way and XPath `contains()` function in the second way.